# How to return multiple results from an async function?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have this function:

```
const memberdata = async function() {
     const name = await doquery('name','members','id',userid);
     return (name);
    };

memberdata().then(v => {
     
    username = v[0].name; //returns John, etc.
}
```

now I want to increase the number of constants like this:

```
const memberdata = async function() {
     const name = await doquery('name','members','id',userid);
     const sex = await doquery('sex','members','id',userid);
     const age = await doquery('age','members','id',userid);
```

but since now I get multiple results instead of just one. How is the syntax for then?

```
memberdata().then(v => {
    username = v[0].name; //returns John, etc.
    usersex = v[0].sex; //returns male, etc.
    userage = v[0].age; //returns 24, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want an Object to hold these, and then return the object.  and if you have multiples, like your example implies, for the array, then you can have an array of objects.  Something like this:

```
const memberdata = async function() {
     const name = await doquery('name','members','id',userid);
     const sex = await doquery('sex','members','id',userid);
     const age = await doquery('age','members','id',userid);
     const returnObject = {name: name, sex: sex, age: age};
     // loop here and push onto an array if needed.
     return returnObject;
```

Comment: Since all depend on userId, you could also parallize the fetching of data and use `Promise.all`.

Comment: do you care to elaborate a little more on how to get each value from object in .then please?

Comment: you can use a for..in loop, and Object.keys() Object.values(), Object.entries(), etc... Maybe I'm not understanding your question?

Comment: you mean inside the .then bracket or before the return in function?

Comment: your question was about returning multiple things.  You can return one thing from any function, but it can be an item made up of other things.  So you'll want to return this object (Promisified if you wish to use a .then afterwards).  Then you deconstruct what you packed inside the function with the calling code.